Convergence of a sequence with norm equal to one

Let $\{ f_n \} _{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset H^{\infty} (\mathbb{D})$
with $\lVert f_n \rVert _{\infty} = 1$. Is there a subsequence $\{
f_{n_k}\}_k$ converging to a function $f \in H^{\infty} (\mathbb{D})$,
uniformly in $\mathbb{D}$?

Following the definition of uniform convergence, and specifically an example from the textbook Gamelin, T. W. (2000). Complex Analysis. Springer Science & Business Media., page 134. where the worst-case estimator is taken as the maximum height of the function, I have assumed that if the norm is one, then the worst-case estimator for this sequence is also one, therefore different from zero and not uniformly convergent. The answer I have written more "mathematically" as a try of a proof:
Being the case that  $\lVert f_n \rVert _{\infty} = \sup\{ |f_n| \} = 1$, therefore the worst-case estimator $\varepsilon_j = 1 \neq 0$, Since the sequence of functions $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$, nor will the subsequence $\{ f_{n_k}\}_k$.
Sorry for the mistakes in notation, I'm a physicist facing CA for the first time.

$H^{\infty} (\mathbb{D})$ is not compact.

You can always get a subsequence which converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Bbb D$ (Montel's theorem), but not necessarily on the whole of $\Bbb D$

$f_n(z)=z^n$ does not admit a uniformly convergent subsequence.

The "Hardy spaces on the unit circle" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space looks interesting.
